# DLL containing ENUM is creating weird behaviour

Tags: c#, dll, enums

Most of you guys will find this as dumb question, but need your genuine help here.

Problem:
I have created a separate project to define constants. I am using that project reference to other 300 projects(basically DLL).Everything was working fine since last week. Now I have changed my constant project to remove some ENUM values.

my code:

```
public enum KVP:int
[EnumMember(Value="1")]
KVP1,
[EnumMember(Value="2")]
KVP2,
[EnumMember(Value="3")]
KVP3,
//[EnumMember(Value="4")]
//KVP4,
[EnumMember(Value="5")]
KVP5
```

I have removed KVP4 from the project and built a new DLL. I have tried to run the application,but with bad luck I got error related to KVP4 which I already removed.

point1: I've just built the constant DLL in which I've made changes.

point2: I haven't updated constant project reference to remaining 300 projects which is not practical,though.

I am getting confused here because If I update other constant values in the DLL(constant project), that works fine. Other Projects start taking the new values automatically which means all othe projects referencing the new updated DLL,but not in the case of ENUM.

**Anyone having any suggestion or remedy to cop up with the issue?**

EDIT:
there must be some difference between the word CONST and ENUM (to the one who requested closing this as duplicate).What should I use if I have to define constants then? A model class with props and static value??

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: KVP4 is still in use,so basically rather than taking value for KVP5(as I have deletedKVP4), it is talking KVP4 and that is creating mess.so, technically I am getting argumentexceptions as  Iam using KVP as argument. Hope I've clearly made my point.

Comment: Why would you remove a value from the enum, if its still in use by other projects?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten that value is now not required as per my client. business requirements man, sucked up! :|

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Constant value not changing when recompiling referenced assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227690/constant-value-not-changing-when-recompiling-referenced-assembly)

Comment: Unless your client is a developer as well they never access that enum directly so there are better ways to solve this. Anyway your question is basically: I made a breaking change in X, now all projects using X stopped working. Well, yes, and there is no proper way around that than either to undo the change, or change (or at least build) all projects using X as well.

Comment: @stijn, this is only case with ENUMS and CONST right, not with a class with string hardcoded vaules

Comment: Re *there must be some difference between the word CONST and ENUM (to the one who requested closing this as duplicate)*: [there is not](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3422198/11683).

Comment: again new thread you have pasted here :) well, that makes difference. I am not a newbie though so yes there is difference between this two:https://www.quora.com/C-programming-language-Difference-between-enum-and-static-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never do such things. You are breaking the system.

> I haven't updated constant project reference to remaining 300 projects which is not practical,though

So, the value is still being used in those 300 projects.
You should try to compile them and see if they compile (they won't).

Instead of deleting the value, you can mark it as `Obsolete` with the `[Obsolete]` attribute.
And slowly start to change the other projects for not using it anymore. Only after you are absolutely 100% sure that no other code uses this value, you can remove it.

Comment: [obsolate] will save from using KVP.KVP4 , but won't help for code which already has KVP.KVP4, right??

Comment: No, the only way is to go through the **entire** codebase and change it that no one will use it. And even then, can you be sure that the value was not saved in the DB? You might have to develop a migration process as well. Good Luck :)

Comment: you're one helping man! So a learning lesson for me is don't create constants and ENUMs that can change. what should I do then? A class with string variables?

Comment: That is not really the lesson, the problem is not with the constants per se, rather that if they represent features which might or might not be available you need a layer in between the constants and the end-user which deals with this. Instead of constants, something like a list of strings read from a config file might deal with some of the issues but you don't state the use case exactly so it's hard to tell.

Comment: @stijn, use case is: I have to change the ENUM after 5 years, till now I was in the impression that this values never gonna change. now , i have to change the ENUM and that piece is referenced in 300 projects. so I have to build those projects again and have to put in PROD, which will create risk of putting 300 DLL which has no code change, though

Comment: @DirtyDeveloper that's not a use case, just short sighted.  At no point during development involving 300 projects did someone ask the question - what if?

Comment: @khargoosh well that is not a business use case, but become a suicide case for me :) Chill mate. what would you do if you have to change like me?

Comment: @DirtyDeveloper If you can't rebuild all the projects, I think this answer is the best you can hope for in your situation - and start planning now for the next time this becomes an issue.